# Getting checkbox value(s) from a Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, html, servlets

I have a servlet with MySQL database in it. It looks like this: [image]

here is the piece of code for it:

```
out.println("<table id = \"main_section\" cellspacing=\"1\" bgcolor=\"red\" > ");
out.println ("<tr> ");
out.println("<td >NUMBER</td>");
out.println("<td >PAYMENT</td>");
out.println("<td >RECEIVER</td>");
out.println("<td >VALUE </td>");
out.println("<td >CHECKBOX</td>");
out.println("</tr>");
out.println("<tr>");
for (int i = 0; i < ex.getExpenses().size(); i++) {
    out.println("<td > " + ex.getExpenses().get(i) + "</td>");

    if (i>0 && (i+1)%4==0) {
        out.println("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\"></td>");
        out.println("</tr><tr>");

    }     
}
out.println("</tr>");
```

What I need to do is to create a submit button that calculates the sum of VALUE of the checked boxes. for instance, if NUMBER 1 and 2 are checked the submit button should give the result of 5577.0 (VALUE 22.0+5555.0).
Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: i have tried to appoint the value of checkbox to the value of VALUE: `double value = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("VALUE"));
             out.println("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkboxname\" value = \"" + value +" \"></td>");` and then get the results by smth like: `request.getParameterValues("checkboxname")`. but it didn't work : (

Answer (score 26):

First of all, you should learn about JSPs and generate your HTML markup from a JSP rather than from the servlet.

Now for your problem. Each of these rows comes from a database table. So each of these rows should have an ID (primary key). Assign the ID of the row to the value of the checkbox. When you submit your form, the servlet will receive all the IDs of the checked checkboxes. Get the values corresponding from these IDs from the database, and sum them (or execute a query that computes the sum directly):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkedRows" value="${idOfCurrentRow}">
```

In the servlet handling the form submission:

```
String[] checkedIds = request.getParameterValues("checkedRows");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by

```
String[] values = req.getParameterValues("checkbox");
```

Comment: and then what? how can you get the row values, using a mystical magic or something like that?

Comment: You can get it by getting values from the array.

Comment: How you can difference between the selected checkboxes and the non-selected in your array with this code? You can check the other answers to get the point :)

Comment: That you manage by just placing the logs or some kind of things by `String []`.

Comment: don't argue guys, i  have to do it using Servlet anyway, so JSP is not the way out : )

Comment: Have you ever programmed in JSP or Servlet ?

Comment: yes i have, but in the thing i have to do now, i can only use servlet

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

> ```
> out.println("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"checkbox\"></td>");
> ```

To read:

```
out.println("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"selected\" value=\""+ex.getExpenses().get(i-1)+"\"></td>");
```

This will create checkboxes that you can identify themselves by the value-tag. I hope that the "number" field is a primary key or the like.

Then on next run. You can get all checked values by:

```
String[] selected = request.getParameters("selected");
```

now, you can just add up the numbers. I don't quite understand how you Expenses-list looks like from the code. Here is just an illustration that will not work but could give you the idea on how to do it:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ex.getExpenses().size(); i++)
  for(int selectedIndex = 0; selectedIndex < selected.length; ++selectedIndex)
    if (ex.getExpenses().get(i) == Integer.parseInt(selected[selectedIndex]))
      sum += ex.getExpenses().get(i-1);
```

Comment: I have tried smth like that ( i wrote it in the comment above) but the problem that i face is that i store my getExpenses.get(i) as Objects and whenever i get to the point: `if (ex.getExpenses().get(i) == Integer.parseInt(selected[selectedIndex]))
` it won't compile because of incompatible operand types Object and int. Adding cast doesn't help. and then how do i pass it all the the submit button, so that i will give the the sum result? thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, now i have changed the getExpenses from Object type to String and did the following: ` if (Integer.parseInt( ex.getExpenses().get(j)) == Integer.parseInt(selected[selectedIndex]))

              sum += Integer.parseInt( ex.getExpenses().get(j-1));` but how i a pass the sum to submit button?

Comment: i have created a form with submit button in it, with action to Servlet where i have the code that sums selected boxes. whenever i select and press submit, it throws NullPointerExcetion at ` for(int selectedIndex = 0; selectedIndex < selected.length; ++selectedIndex)`

Comment: @Gibsy: The null pointer exception probably comes if no checkbox is checked (which is the case when you load the page for the first time). Surround the loop above be an `if (selected != null)`

Comment: this is what i've done ( with your help : ) ): `Dao ex = ExpensesDao.getDao(); 
  String[] selected = request.getParameterValues("selected");
       
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < ex.getExpenses().size(); j++)
         if (selected !=null) {
          for(int selectedIndex = 0; selectedIndex < selected.length; ++selectedIndex)
                    if (Integer.parseInt(ex.getExpenses().get(j)) == Integer.parseInt(selected[selectedIndex]))
              sum += Integer.parseInt( ex.getExpenses().get(j-1));
         
         }
        out.println(sum);

 }`

Comment: but the output i get is 0. smth is wrong with `if (Integer.parseInt(ex.getExpenses().get(j)) == Integer.parseInt(selected[selectedIndex]))`. the compiler doesn't find the equity. i have assigned the value to check box =  ex.getExpenses().get(j-1) and my primary key is Number, what am i doing wrong?