# How to delete rows inside table using servlets

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

**Is it possible to delete rows in a table while using html inside servlets i.e without using javascript and jsp.**

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to delete rows in a table on SQL server?

Comment: @Minh, actually I am using a .html file in which inside a form I make entries inside textbox, checkbox etc store them in oracle database and action of form is directed towards a servlet in which I display all values that I entered in html file by retrieving data from database using ResultSet and setting them inside a table and displaying that table inside servlet.So now I want to delete some entries in that table. How can I do that.

Comment: When you say delete inside a table , technically yes you can , practically no you cant ... If you are building the HTML using a dataset , removing the item from the dataset or list can indeed result in you removing a row in your html table. If you are building your html as a sting in the servlet then again possible.Post your code and we can assist

Comment: @Aamir, you need a `<form>` with its action to your servlet. You need send row(s) id to your server via checkbox id, hidden field...

Comment: @Minh,how to set checkbox id for each row.

Comment: @Aamir, you can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658945/getting-checkbox-values-from-a-servlet. I don't want to retype :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you could "delete" rows in a Table(?) only via "HTML". You only need a `<form>`-Element which transfers your wishes to the server, which in response sends you an updated version of the page. Although that is awkward and not really smart - it is possible.

Comment: @can you elaborate it please.

Comment: what wishes I need to send.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o7b9hrq8/1/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `tables` for html page designing. Using `div` for designing would be more flexible and reliable in the long run as it is handled by all browsers pretty well compared to `tables` as they are becoming obsolete when it comes to `html` designing. Plus there are lot plugins like `jQuery` that can make deleting, adding or manipulating html components as in your case `rows` effortless. I strongly recommend you take time to think about this approach. Your problem can be solved by giving your rows unique ids or class name to delete them. But that will be a crude solution. Use `ajax` function of `jQuery` to call your servlet and you can manipulate your `html` design as per the response returned. Plus this call to server do not require page submission. Which is helpful in lot of situations. Good luck.